# return true not change button name

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I think my question is too hard to understand. Sorry for that.

I got two form were one is add friend button which is link to prompt box input and another one form include disabled unfriend button. Once click add friend the prompt box input appear and insert into database while unfriend btn can enable to click.

Now my problem is data can insert into table but unfriend button cannot enable to click. Whenever I press add friend button it enable unfriend button to click but the change not stay for so long.

In few second the unfriend button disabled like not Press addfriend. I think the return true not working. i try to put return false, the button work as I expected but it never submit the form. I want the unfriend button is enable to click after press add button and form also can submit. I am using simple javascript.

```
<script>

function myFunction(form){
    var subject = prompt("Please enter Subject that want to study");
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    var add = document.getElementById("add");
    btn.disabled=false;
    add.disabled=true;
    if (subject == null){
     form['subject'].value= subject;
    add.value="request sent";
    return false;
    form.submit();
    }
    else if(subject != null) {
        form['subject'].value= subject;
        add.value="request sent";
        btn.disabled=false;
        add.disabled=true;
        return true;
        form.submit();
    }

}
function unfriend(form){

    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    var add = document.getElementById("add");
    add.disabled=false;
    btn.disabled=true;
    add.value="request sent";   
    return true;
}
</script>

                 <form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off"> 

                   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>" />
                 <input type="hidden" id="subject"  name="subject" data-uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['sid'] ;?>/>
                 <td><input type="submit" onclick="return myFunction(form)"name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="add" class="btn" value="add" /> </form>
                <form>                
                 <input type="submit" value="unfriend" id="btn"  onclick="unfriend(form);" disabled="" /> </td>   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" id="subject"  name="subject" data-uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['sid'] ;?>/>
Change this to : <input type="hidden" id="subject"  name="subject" data-uid="<?php echo $_SESSION['sid'] ;?>"/> and check
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1x0es4qf/1/ - check the error {"error":"key missing: title"}